# Quaternions and translations

Tags: c++, c, opengl, math, quaternions

I created a small program that can rotate a 3D object in space.

To sum it up quickly, I created a function to perform matrix rotations using quaternions:

```
void        matrix_rotate(float matrix[][4], float angle, t_vec4 rotation_axis)
{
    float   rotate[4][4];
    t_vec4  quat;

    quat = quaternion_create(angle, rotation_axis); // Create a quaternion from an axis-angle representation
    quaternion_to_matrix(rotate, quat);             // Convert the quaternion to a rotation matrix
    matrix_multiply(matrix, rotate);                // Multiply the rotation matrix
}
```

So I can for instance perform a 90-degrees rotation on the y-axis to the model matrix (the `t_vec4` is a 4D vector, composed of 4 floats x, y, z, w):

```
matrix_rotate(model, 90.0, (t_vec4){0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0});
```

It works so far. But the rotation is related to my world origin (0, 0, 0). I would like to translate the rotation axis of my quaternion.

How can I translate the rotation axis of a quaternion to rotate an object around its **own axis** and not the world origin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is really no need to use quaternions here. If all you want is create a matrix that rotates around a given axis by a given angle, then [you can just do that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle). You're effectively already doing it anyways, just via the detour of using a quaternion in the middle…

Quaternions can only represent rotations. One could use [dual quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion) to work with rotations and translations in a unified manner. However, that would seem to be massive overkill here. To get a matrix that rotates around an axis that passes through a point that is not the origin, you can just first translate the coordinate system such that the point you want your rotation axis to go through becomes the origin. Then you apply the rotation. And then you translate everything back. So if **p** is the vector of coordinates of the point you want the rotation axis to go through, you first translate everything by **-p**, then you rotate, and then you translate back by **p**…

Comment: I am using quaternions because I use the mouse to rotate the object around XYZ, I want to avoid gimbal lock. Is using a rotation matrix from the three combined euler matrices truly avoiding gimbal lock ?

Comment: Also, why does quaternions perform rotation around (0, 0) ?

Comment: @Prion Your example does not show that you are combining a new rotation with an existing one, which is where quaternions are useful. It only shows you create an single rotation matrix from an axis and angle for which quaternions are not needed.

Comment: Contrary to what appears to be popular belief, gimbal lock has nothing to do with matrices, and quaternions do not somehow magically protect against gimbal lock. Gimbal lock is a problem with Euler angle rotation sequences. It does not matter whether you represent your rotations as matrices or quaternions. If you use Euler angles, you can get gimbal lock. To avoid gimbal lock, avoid using Euler angles…

Comment: Doing three subsequent rotations using quaternions in the Euler fashion does not involve gimbal lock if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Prion It does, because the problem of gimbal lock is a consequence of the whole "doing three rotations around the coordinate axes" idea. It has nothing to do with matrices. I invite you to convince yourself by trying it out… ;-)

Comment: So why are we using quaternions if it brings no benefits compared to Euler angle ?

Comment: I am very confused, if doing three subsequent quaternions does not prevent gimbal lock, what are the benefits of this “powerful” mathematical tool ? One should just create a rotation matrix.

Comment: Euler angles are an approach to describe orientations in space as the result of three individual rotations around the coordinate axes. Quaternions, on the other hand, are just one of many ways to represent rotations. You can do Euler angles using whatever method to represent the individual rotations you like. The benefits of quaternions over matrices have to do with numeric stability and efficiency when computing long chains of rotations.

Comment: Wikipedia does mention that quaternions prevent gimbal lock: “*In addition, unlike Euler angles, they are not susceptible to gimbal lock*”. How do you explain this ?

Comment: @Prion The point is, converting axis and angle pair to a quaternion and *then* to a matrix is no different from constructing the matrix directly from an axis and an angle. If gimbal lock is really a problem to you, you have to use a persistent quaternion to store the current rotation.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia is probably a bit misleading here. I didn't check out the article, but note how it puts Quaternions in contrast to Euler angles. One can only assume that what the article was trying to say is that representing an orientation directly in the axis and angle form that a single Quaternion corresponds to avoids the issue of gimbal lock when compared to representing an orientation by the angles of an Euler sequence, which is true. However, as soon as you construct a Quaternion from an Euler sequence you *are* using an Euler sequence and will be subject to gimbal lock…

Comment: Thank you, it makes it clearer. By the way, why are matrices operations always relative to the *world origin* (0, 0, 0) ?

Comment: A matrix describes a transformation of the coordinate frame. It is essential to understand that all a coordinate transform does is take coordinates relative to one coordinate system and turn them into the coordinates of the same point just relative to another coordinate system. There is no such thing as an absolute "world origin" as far as your matrix is concerned. A matrix basically just represents the "difference" between two coordinate systems. Matrix operations are not really "relative to the world origin". Each matrix operation is relative to the coordinate system of the previous one…

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is the first rotate an object in world's origin and then move it in the desired position. So just swap rotation and position matrices.